Theme error: no theme named 'furo' found (missing theme.conf?)
I would like to preface that I am a complete beginner to Sphinx documentation.
That being said, I have had immense difficulties trying to troubleshoot this issue.
I am trying to use the "furo" html theme in my project, but for some reason am unable to do so.
Here's what I've attempted so far:

I've successfully installed furo using pip install furo.
I've installed Sphinx 8.0.2, but for some reason, sphinx-build --version returns sphinx-build 5.0.2
I've updated the html_theme option in conf.py to point to 'furo'

Additionally, I have also attempted to add 'furo' to extensions in conf.py, but I still get the theme error mentioned in the title.

This sounds like you installed things in unexpected locations, as everything else sounds correct. Did you install everything into the same Python virtual environment? Try pip freeze to show installed packages and their versions in your active virtual environment.

A good practice is to always install your python packages within a Virtual Environment. It basically prevents packages from breaking (In your case here). Here's what I would do:

Navigate to a new directory, and set up a Virtual Environment inside it. Do this with

python -m venv venv
.\venv\Scripts\activate

For MacOS/Linux
python -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate


Install the Python Packages with: pip install sphinx, and pip install furo.

Enable the theme in my conf.py file


html_theme = "furo"

Apologies for the late response.
